# Redux: Get list of actions fired

Tags: angular, typescript, redux

I am using Redux in my angular project to get data to the state and make some API calls and so on. I notice that redux devtools has a list of all the actions that have been executed. Is there a way to get a list of actions fired in my angular app?

I want to send the list of actions to the backend and process them further.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There is no built-in list of dispatched actions, but since every reducer is called whenever an action is dispatched, you can create something that stores each action by adding redux middleware or rolling your own reducer to accumulate actions.

Answer (score 0):

How I've done it in the past is creating a logging middleware for the store. Here's a decent example. https://github.com/Webiks/angular-redux-middleware-example.

Essentially it captures all the actions, you either do something with them based on the actions or return the next function for the store to continue

```
export function loggerMiddleware(store) {
  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      // log a fancy message and action
      console.log('Hello, this is your captain speaking.', action);
      // continue to the next action
      return next(action);
    };
  };
}
```

This could also be rewritten to something like the following, just to shorten it up:

```
export const loggerMiddleware = store => next => action {
      // log a fancy message and action
      console.log('Hello, this is your captain speaking.', action);
      // continue to the next action
      return next(action);
    };
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *super* hacky way of getting them out in under 30 seconds.  It makes a lot of assumptions, but it may work for you.

https://reergymerej.github.io/blog/2019/06/14/janky-event-exports.html

- Type `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` into the console.
- Double-click to open the source in VM.
- Pretty-print.
- Breakpoint :356.
- Go back to the tool and jump to an action. This should hit your breakpoint.

```js
Object.keys(t.actionsById).forEach((id) =>
  console.log(t["actionsById"][id].action.type))
```